# Call to C# async method doesn't return in Web Application

Tags: c#, async-await

I'm trying out async/await code in a new C# 4.5 web application on VS 2013.  It's a web application running on my developer machine under IISExpress.  I'm setting a breakpoint in the async method and can see that the method completes as expected.  But then the next line of code after the await call is not appearing to get hit.  I have a breakpoint there, which doesn't get hit and I've tried stepping through the code.  It just seems to get hung there waiting infinitely.  I tried running the same code in a Console app, and that IS working.  **Which makes me wonder if async/await debugging doesn't work in web applications, or perhaps it has something to do with IISExpress?  Or is there something else I'm missing?**

The code is pretty basic and looks like this:

```
public async Task SomeMethodAsync(string parameter1)
{

}
```

... the code calling the above async method:

```
await SomeMethodAsync("some value");
```

Comment: What Web framework are you using?
If you are using Asp.Net MVC you must use async actions in controllers: 

 http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/performance/using-asynchronous-methods-in-aspnet-mvc-4

Comment: Does the code run past the await? Put some for of logging there to see if it's a "debug" issue or whether it's possible that your async method never completes.

Comment: @DaniCE, thanks, it's a classic Web Form.

Comment: @NielsFilter, I added 3 Debug.WriteLine statements.  1 before the await call ("before"), 1 after the await call ("after"), and 1 at the very end of the async method ("completed").  The "before" and "completed" debug statements are appearing, but the "after" statement is not appearing.  This is consistent with what I'm seeing with my breakpoints.  It appears that the async method completes, and then the next line of code after the await statement is not running.

Comment: @Ben, that's odd behaviour, is it possible to share some more code?

Comment: @NielsFilter, I got it working.  I'll post more details in an Answer.  It was other code (although not much of it) that was causing this to happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it working.  It was the structure of the code (not included in my question) that was leading to this.  The fact that it's a Web Forms app is also appears to be a factor.  The original code looked like this:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var task = RunSample();
    task.Wait();
}

private static async Task RunSample()
{
    await SomeMethodAsync("some value");
}
```

It turns out that while the async method was running, execution of the code was going to `task.Wait()` in the button click handler, and waiting there.  I wouldn't have expected the code to go there (this was code I had copied from a console app...)

I decided to move the RunSample() code into the button click handler, like so, eliminating RunSample():

```
protected async void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    await SomeMethodAsync("some value");
}
```

This led to an error initially from the compiler that Async="true" needs to be added to the @Page directive.  After doing that, it started working as expected.  Even with my original code, and Async="true" there, that didn't work either.  The key I believe is for the button click handler to be marked with the `async` keyword.

Thanks to @NielsFilter and @DaniCE for follow up questions getting me to look at this further.

Comment: Great. Something important to remember is to try not to mix TPL methods such as .Wait and .Result with async and await. Since await actually "captures the context" and .Wait and .Result are blocking, waiting for await to return a result, you can end up with deadlocks. For more details see number 2 of the async pitfalls in my blog here: https://filteredcode.wordpress.com/2015/05/27/async-pitfalls-part-4-of-4/

Comment: I have [a blog post](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html) that describes this problem in detail. You may also find my [MSDN article on async best practices](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx) and [MSDN article on async ASP.NET](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn802603.aspx) helpful.